# Node naming and running. rospy.init_node() and .launch file nodes

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

For learning purposes I have created a simple launch file and simple python scripts.
This is my launch file

```
<launch>
    <node name="rf_sim_node_1" pkg="rf_trilateration" type="rf_sim_node.py" args="5,5"/>
    <node name="rf_sim_node_2" pkg="rf_trilateration" type="rf_sim_node.py" args="-5,-5"/>
    <node name="rf_sim_node_3" pkg="rf_trilateration" type="rf_sim_node.py" args="-5,5"/>
    <node name="rf_sim_node_4" pkg="rf_trilateration" type="rf_sim_node.py" args="5,-5"/>
    <node name="rf_trilateration_service" pkg="rf_trilateration" type="rf_trilateration_server.py"/>
</launch>
```

and this is the rf_sim_node.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy


def start_server():
    rospy.init_node("rf_node", anonymous=True)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

When I launch my file with roslaunch

`$rosnode list` gives out this

```
/rf_sim_node_1
/rf_sim_node_2
/rf_sim_node_3
/rf_sim_node_4
/rf_trilateration_service
/rosout
```

Now I am wondering what does rospy.init_node does actually do?. I was expecting to see "rf_node-14 " kinda nodes but end up wtih the node names from the launching file.

What if I make multiple calls to rospy.init_node() will I get new nodes or am I doing something wrong. I read at rospy documentation that I should only call this once but why is the nodes name defined or created at creation of process ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191839/node-naming-and-running.-rospy.init_node()-and-.launch-file-nodes./) by [Ali.Akdurak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20110/ali.akdurak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you have a look at [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown).

The short explanation for the observed phenomenon would be:

`rosp.init_node()` defines a default name which is used if you don't overwrite it (e.g. `rosrun rf_trilateration rf_sim_node.py`). The `name` tag in the launch file on the other hand overwrites this name and therefore you will always find the node named the same as the `name` tag in the launch file.

The most important part about naming nodes is that the name has to be unique. If you try to start two nodes with the same name, the first node would be killed when the second one is started. The argument `anonymous=True` makes sure that you always have a unique name for your node. If you would run:

```
rosrun rf_trilateration rf_sim_node.py
rosrun rf_trilateration rf_sim_node.py
```

so the same command twice, you would see a different `rosnode list` output.

*Edit:* To answer the comment

`name` is actually a mandatory field. If you give an empty string `name=""` it will create a name from the `type=myscript.py` tag `myscript_py_machinename_id_id_id` which is the same as using `name=$(anon some_name)` which will create nodes called: `some_name_manchinename_id_id_id` so it uses the name `some_name` instead of the name of the binary or python script given to `type`.

The name tag however voids the default name and the `anonymous` attribute given to `init_node()`. So from my experience and what I could find on the internet, there is no way of using the default name when starting the node via roslaunch.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ali.Akdurak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20110/ali.akdurak/) on 2014-09-04**:
I see thank you for your answer and the link. Just to be clear roslaunch's  attribute overwrites whatever name I can give at init_node parameter inside my code. Is there a way I can use roslaunch without giving node names?

**Comment by [Ali.Akdurak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20110/ali.akdurak/) on 2014-09-04**:
Thanks a lot :D, You were very helpfull

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-09-04**:
You're very welcome.